Android Intune SDK: Attempt to access uninitialized OfflineComponents
In my application the user can login with MS MSIL library.
Then I'm fetching configuration from MAM (10.0.0) like in MS guide:
val configManager = MAMComponents.get(MAMAppConfigManager::class.java)
val appConfig = configManager!!.getAppConfig(identity)


But I'm getting the following error:
Fatal Exception: java.lang.AssertionError: Attempt to access uninitialized OfflineComponents
       at com.microsoft.intune.mam.client.app.offline.OfflineComponents$UninitializedContextProvider.get(OfflineComponents.java:379)
       at com.microsoft.intune.mam.client.app.offline.OfflineComponents.get(OfflineComponents.java:282)
       at com.microsoft.intune.mam.client.app.MAMComponents.get(MAMComponents.java:639)

I found an old post
Where the problem is solved with MAMComponents.initialize(appContext).
But API doesn't mentioned in MS documentation.

Does some one has experience with such issue?
I'm using MAM SDK 10.0.0.
